# Remove whitespace between bbcode tags in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, whitespace, bbcode

I need to remove all whitespace between adjacent BBCode tags in a string without affecting whitespaces in a BBCode's text. The input is something like:

```
*[ul]
    [li]List Item 1[/li]
    [li]List Item 2[/li]
[/ul]*
```

After removing the new lines and tabs, it looks like this:

```
[ul] [li]List Item 1[/li] [li]List Item 2[/li] [/ul]
```

To ensure that the whitespace doesn't interfere with the code, I need to remove all whitespace between the commands (`[ul]`, `[li]`, `[/ul]`, `[/li]`). How can I achieve this?

Comment: How does it end up on one line? What have you tried to remove the spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, using a regex and [`preg_replace()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$text = preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]\s*\[/', '[\1][', $text);
```

You can visualize how this regex works [here](https://regex101.com/r/oU6qP6/1).

Answer (score 1):

Pattern breakdown:

```
(?:^|\[[^]]+])  #match start of string or opening or closing bb tag
\K              #forget the matched characters so far
\s+             #match one or more whitespace characters 
(?=\[[^]]+]|$)  #lookahead for another opening or closing bb tag or the end of the string
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/73Vv4))

```
$bb = ' [ul]
    [li] List Item 1 [/li]
    [li] List Item 2 [/li]
[/ul] ';

var_export(
    preg_replace(
        '#(?:^|\[[^]]+])\K\s+(?=\[[^]]+]|$)#',
        '',
        $bb
    )
);
```

Regex is, of course, a bbcode-ignorant tool it doesn't know if it is matching legitimate bbcode tags or just characters that look like bbcode tags.  To improve strictness, you can nominate the tags that you wish to whitelist.  For your sample string, the following will do: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/cnTpH)

```
#(?:^|\[/?(?:ul|li)])\K\s+(?=\[/?(?:ul|li)]|$)#
```